# Get the primary group ID

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

Trying to get all the groups a user belongs to, INCLUDING the primary group:

Doing something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP:/domainXYZ, userx, passwordx); 
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}{1}))", userY, LDAP://domainXYZ);
SearchResultCollection resultColln= searcher.FindOne();

string actualGroupName =string.empty;
string grp ="";
foreach (SearchResult singleRes in resultColln)
{
   foreach (object value in singleRes.Properties["memberof"])
   {
       grp = value.ToString();
       Console.WriteLine("group:{0} ", grp);
   }
}
```

This gives me all the groups except the primary group.  Is there a way to get the primary group **name**, using the `primaryGroupID` in addition to the other groups?

Comment: Does this help? http://dunnry.com/blog/2005/01/18/DeterminingYourPrimaryGroupInActiveDirectoryUsingNET.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run another search using the following search filter

```
string.Format("(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(primaryGroupToken={0}))", singleRes.Properties["primaryGroupID"]);
```

`primaryGroupToken` is a calculated attribute that automatically generated by Active Directory when the group is created.  The `primaryGroupID` assigned to the user is storing this value.

Actually, if you want a *really* easy way, I would suggest [UserPrincipal.GetGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getgroups.aspx) is really easy.  The only thing is that you can find it only in .NET 3.5 or later.

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "YourUser"))
    {
        foreach (Principal p in user.GetGroups())
        {
             Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }
    }
 }
```

`GetGroups` returns you only the group that immediately contains your user, including its primary group.  If you want to get all the nested groups, you can use `GetAuthorizationGroups`.

Comment: I think your first example needs to be: `singleRes.Properties["primaryGroupID"].Value` instead of simply: `singleRes.Properties["primaryGroupID"]`

Comment: And beyond that, you cannot use a constructed attribute as an LDAP filter: http://blogs.technet.com/b/efleis/archive/2004/11/17/258710.aspx